# sum of independent normally distributed random variables in regression model

Tags: regression, self-study, mathematical-statistics

In the simple linear regression model, $\hat{b}$ is the sum of independent normally
distributed random variables .

Is it false because it talks about $\hat{b}$ and not $b$? because in the simple regression model the equation is $y=a+bx+e$ and not $y=\hat{b}x+a$

Comment: same as https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/432655/meaning-of-hatb-of-the-linear-regression-model-true-false